# How to make changes to the sibling element if child of an element is focused?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to change colour of css.seperator when css.searchBarInput is in focus, how can I do this?

Here's my HTML for reference:

```
<div className={css.searchBarBase}>
  <div className={css.searchBarFirstDiv}>
    <label className={css.searchBarDivContent} htmlFor="location-search-input">
      <div className={css.searchBarHeadingFont}>Location</div>
      <input
      id="location-search-input"
      className={css.searchBarInput}
      />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div className={css.seperator}/>
</div>
```

Here's my attempt at it:

```
.searchBarBase > div:focus-within + div {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: These elements are NOT siblings.

Comment: @Paulie_D please reread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one focusable element inside `searchBarBase` then you can look at focus-within.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within
>
> The `:focus-within` CSS pseudo-class matches an element if the element or any of its descendants are focused. In other words, it represents an element that is itself matched by the `:focus` pseudo-class or has a descendant that is matched by `:focus`. (This includes descendants in [shadow trees](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM).)

selector to use for you would be `.searchBarFirstDiv:focus-within ~.seperator {/* style to apply here */}`